# NonSerialized for multiple properties

Tags: c#, nonserializedattribute

Do i have to put [NonSerialized] for each property of a class?

```
[NonSerialized]
public Cell Owner;
[NonSerialized]
public double Time
```

Comment: Yes, you have to (if you want all these fields not to be serialized)

Comment: No; only the ones that you don't want to be serialized.  Also, those are fields, not properties.

Comment: `[NonSerialized]` suggests you are using `BinaryFormatter`, in which case I think the other important advice is: *be really careful there* - it can be brittle. Personally, I always advise people to use a different serializer; pretty much *any other* serializer than this one. Except `NetDataContractSerializer` - don't use that either ;p

Comment: particularly i have a list of ball class. class holds information for position, velocity and other misc. properties of ball. I want to save/resume in any moment. When resuming I need to know only position and velocity. Do you suggest any other safe and simple method other than serialization? Because i'm not a programmer and my main purpose is something else. I don't want to get drowned in programming practices and lines of codes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the attribute definition (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx):

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Field, Inherited = false)]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public sealed class NonSerializedAttribute : Attribute
```

`AttributeTargets.Field` tells you that it can be used on the fields and is not inheritable

So you have to use it **on the fields that you don't want** to be serializable.